# What does the % number reflect? Is that the number of clicks vs. clicks to the whole site?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics In-Page Analytics report I see `6.7%` and `159` clicks.

What does the `%` number reflect? Is that the number of clicks vs. clicks to the whole site?

Is that `159` clicks on search button is `6.7%` of your total clicks on current page or whole site?

[image]

Comment: Has chosen to ask it here instead: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55690/what-does-this-number-in-google-analytics-reflect

Comment: sorry I've found that this is not the right place and asked my question in webmasters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google:

```
These indicate the links users clicked. The numbers inside represent the percentage 
for the metric you chose in the Viewing menu.
```

Read more here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558864?hl=en